# Displaying a list of errors,when consecutive data is too far from the average,

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, floating-action-button

I want to do 2 things:
display all voltages that differ from the average by more than 10% of the average and display all pairs of consecutive hours where the change from the voltage at one hour to the next is greater than 15% of the average.I have come into trouble with the second part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
int i, problem = 0, index;
float voltage[6];
float average, average10, average15, dif, total;
int main(){
total = 0.0;
 for( index = 0; index < 6; index++ ){
  printf( "Enter a voltage for hour %d: ", index+1 );
  scanf( "%f", &voltage[index] );
  total += voltage[index];
 }
 average = total / 6.0;
 average10 = average / 10;
 average15 = average / 100 * 15;
 printf("The average is %1.1f\n", average);
 printf("10%% = %1.1f\n", average10);
 printf("15%% = %1.1f\n", average15);

 for(index = 0; index < 6; index++){
 dif = fabs(voltage[index] - average);
 if(dif > (average10)){
     problem++;
     if(problem == 1){
         printf("The following problems occurred:\n");}
         printf("%d. Voltage at hour %d was %1.1f (difference of %1.1f volts)\n", problem, (i ++)+1, voltage[index], dif);

 }
 }

 for(index = 1; index < 6; index++){
 dif = fabs((voltage[i] - voltage[i-1] > average15));
 if(dif > average15){
     problem++;
     if(problem == 1){
         printf("The following problems occurred:\n");}
         printf("%d Voltage change from hour %d to %d was %1.1f", problem, i, (i ++)+1 , dif);
     }
 }


    if(problem = 0) printf("No problems were encountered."); 
 }
```

This displays the first part fine apart from the problem hours dont always display the right values  (as seen here for problem number 2 not enough rep to embed sorry)  http://gyazo.com/34fa038b11bf85effa195232f952cd76

but absolutely nothing appears for the second part or the printf if no problems occur . Do you guys have any ideas on how to make the values on the problems correctly line up and on why im not getting anything back from the second for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a typo here:

```
 dif = fabs((voltage[i] - voltage[i-1] > average15));
 /* This means dif = fabs((0)); 
  * dif = fabs((1));
  * as the result of the > operator is 0 or 1
  **/
```

Probably should be

```
 dif = fabs(voltage[i] - voltage[i-1]);
```

Comment: yea thanks, mind fart for that one , for the sake of completion the no errors message wouldn't show due to being = instead of == and with some testing I seem to have managed to get it running correctly , thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, the tricky thing is it is valid C, no compiler warning or error to warn you, so it was an unlucky typo